# Disable my application in Android Accessibility settings

Tags: android, accessibility, ussd

My app uses Accessibility service to parse USSD response. I've added intent to open Accessibility settings so user could enable it. After it's enabled, app can read USSD messages and release USSD response dialog.
How to disable my app in Accessibility settings programmatically if it doesn't need reading USSD messages anymore?

Comment: You can disable the entire component via `PackageManager` or you can set your service to stop receiving events using `setServiceInfo`, but you can't disable the service in accessibility settings.

Comment: Can you tell me how to read ussd response?

Comment: Hi Dubrovin, I am also working on the same concept . Can you please help me for this.

my question is in below link :-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485420/android-ussd-which-sim-receive-a-ussd-message-or-which-sim-slot-receives-a-ussd

Comment: @alanv even if I disabled my accessibility service component via PackageManager, the service its still visible in Settings -> Accessibility. I expect if I set to DISABLED the component via getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting, to not be shown in Settings -> Accessibility. But that does not seem to be the case. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The `AccessibilityService` has a `disableSelf()` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your contribution. But could you please include some details about this method, perhaps a link to some helpful documentation. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.