# Android USSD which sim receive a ussd message or which sim slot receives a ussd message (dual sim phone)

Tags: android, mobile, ussd, dual-sim

I am able to capture the incoming ussd message, but how to compare the incoming ussd message in case of dual sim phone? If I receive a ussd message alert how can I know that the incoming ussd message is for which sim?

Comment: @SachimArora How did manage capturing the USSD responses? Can you share please?

Answer (score 0):

Started with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) for staring info, not much. Found out there was / is a [security](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJhq7DmefPAhWE1BoKHbAMCUkQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.troopers.de%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F12%2FTROOPERS13-Dirty_use_of_USSD_codes_in_cellular-Ravi_Borgaonkor.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHrxTr3sDkxZpHbsbq1TG6gg-JfGQ) (pdf warning) problem with it. Then jackpot: [specks](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/03/0390/05.00.00_60/gsmts_0390v050000p.pdf) (pdf warning). As I scimmed it, I don't think you will find the info you want in the USSD message itself. It is probably somewhere in the handshake before that. But did not find it.

tldr: it's not in the USSD message itself.